# Swift creating angles on button click, but in opposit direction

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I am creating a circle (Using `CGContext`) with angle of 90, 180 & 280. As we know that 90 degree angle shape like letter 'L', but I am getting opposite shape of 'L', then [Angles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7WbA.png).

Following this image, I don't want to get it like this, so what can I do ? please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Add your sample code here.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/l13hu2s5rvxzjal/lineCreate%203.zip?dl=0 this is link of my sample app

Comment: If you don't know already, it may help to know that the origin is in the top left, not the bottom left. http://www.functionx.com/illustrations/origin1.gif

Comment: How can i make origin from  bottom left?

Comment: @devxoss I would suggest not changing the origin, as it is a standard and you intend to share codebase with some one else.

Comment: @devxoss formula is simple..angle_cal = angles - 90.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it with one of following solution.
1) Rotate your view (button) to -90 degree.
Or 
2) Trickle values of angle while drawing as following:

```
func drawCircle(angles : Double) {


    let angleToDraw =  angles - 90  
    let startCircleAngle = CGFloat(269.9/180 * M_PI)
    let endCircleAngle =  CGFloat(270/180 * M_PI)

    let center = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width / 2.0, self.frame.size.height / 2.0);
    let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    CGContextBeginPath(ctx!)

    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx!, 5)
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx!,UIColor.redColor().CGColor)

    let x:CGFloat = center.x
    let y:CGFloat = center.y
    let radius: CGFloat = 100.0
    CGContextAddArc(ctx!, x, y, radius, startCircleAngle , endCircleAngle, 1)

        CGContextAddArc(ctx!, x, y, 1, startCircleAngle, startCircleAngle, 0)
    CGContextSaveGState(ctx!)

    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx!, x, y)
    // rotation supplied in radians

    CGContextRotateCTM(ctx!, CGFloat(M_PI*(angleToDraw)/180))

    CGContextStrokePath(ctx!)
    let path = CGPathCreateMutable()
    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, 0, 0)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, radius, 1)
    CGContextAddPath(ctx!, path)
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx!, 4)
    CGContextScaleCTM(ctx!, -1.0, 1.0)
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx!,UIColor.blackColor().CGColor)

    CGContextStrokePath(ctx!)

}
```